# JSON JsonPath -> get Array Value that contains String

Tags: json, jsonpath

Hi I have a JSON Object:

```
{      
    "idContainer": 
    [
        "213=135864",
        "312=35947"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to access the string `135864` that is after `213=` (`213` is a kind of key inside of the array value, I get the data formatted like this)

- I can not say for certain that it is the first element in the Array,
  just that it begins with  the "key" `213=`
- The String result of my Xpath expression should be optimally just `135864` and no single or double quotes

1.) I am trying to find a filter expression like this `idContainer[?('213=*')]` which returns me this element `"213=135864"`

2.) More convenient would be if I could filter the result even more and just return `135864` but I don't know if this is possible with JSON XPath Syntax

Thanks for help :)

If necessary I could also use Java expressions, but my favorite Solution would be pure JsonPath

Comment: For me this works: `idContainer[?(@.213 contains '135864')]`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jayway JSONPath, and if you're working in JAVA you probably are, you can use regular expressions in a filter condition, viz.

```
$.idContainer[?(@ =~ /213=.*/)]
```

That produces

```
[
   "213=135864"
]
```

But there's no way using Jayway to produce

```
[
    135864
]
```